# Python tkinter overrideredirect - How to make my window movable again

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

**After I run the code it makes my window unmovable, and I was wondering how would i make it interact with 
MOUSE1**

EDIT1: So this is what i came up with, but it doesnt work like it should, it just "teleports" the window around.

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)

#takes x, y coordinates of your mouse when u realese MOUSE1
def move_window(event):
    global root
    x_coord = event.x
    y_coord = event.y
    y_coord = str(event.y)
    x_coord = str(event.x)
    root.geometry('+'+x_coord+'+'+y_coord)


root.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', move_window)
root.mainloop()
```

EDIT2: SOLVED! I realised the position of the mouse in the code above takes the position x,y INSIDE the tkinter window, not on the screen, I will use the module
*pyautogui* for that

Comment: By interact are you talking about moving the window around using mouse1, or interacting inside the window?

Comment: Yes, moving the window using mouse1, I can still interact inside the window normally, but i can't move it